# How to configure ESlint to fix indent only

Tags: node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am linting old NodeJS code and I want to clear out all indent issues before I start fixing the rest.

How do I configure ESlint to only show and fix the `indent` issues only?

Answer (score 9):

By using eslint in the command line with the proper options:

`node node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint --fix --parser babel-eslint --ext js --no-eslintrc  --rule 'indent: [1,4,{SwitchCase: 1}]' src/`

Change these options according to your requirements

`--fix` to auto fix.

`--parser babel-eslint` the parser from my eslint.rc.

`--ext js` to lint only js files.

`--no-eslintrc` otherwise all rules from your eslintrc will be executed.

`--rule 'indent: [1,4,{SwitchCase: 1}]'` the rule you want to execute (you can copy paste it from your eslint.rc, it has to be single quoted (the double quotes from the original json were removed).

`src/` the target folder.

[eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface)

Comment: For complete noobs like myself : is there an even more basic parser than babel which doesn't require to install an extra package? (i.e. out of the box). I mean, if eslint is able to complain about indentation issues without babel, surely it can fix them too without it?

Comment: What do you think eslint uses internally :) ?( espree and a lot more....)
If you do not need a complete javascript implementation, your lightest solution could be using a parser generator like PEGJS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pegjs)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your normal .eslintrc file to keep your configuration (parser, plugins, rule config, etc), you can use [eslint-nibble](https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-nibble) with the `--rule= indent`  flag.  This will respect your normal configuration, but only show you errors from that rule, and give you the option to fix only those, if the rule is auto-fixable.

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of eslint-nibble.